# Oracle SQL, conditional foreign key

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a problem with implementing DB. I have 2 tables:

```
 CREATE TABLE TAB1
 (
    TAB1_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TAB1_BOOL VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL CHECK (TAB1_BOOL IN('OPT1', 'OPT2'))
 );
 CREATE TABLE TAB2
 (
   TAB2_ID INT NOT NULL
 );
```

I would like to make TAB2_ID as foreign key of TAB1_ID, but TAB2_ID can be only these TAB1_IDs which rows in table TAB1 are marked with TAB1_BOOL == OPT1. For example:

```
TAB1 contains 2 rows: 
1. 'TAB1_ID==1' 'TAB1_BOOL==OPT1', 
2. 'TAB1_ID==2' 'TAB1_BOOL==OPT2'.
Now, statement like:
INSERT INTO TAB2 (TAB2_ID) VALUES (2);
should be rejected because row with TAB1_ID==2 is marked with OPT2
```

Is it possible to make this in Oracle SQL ?

Comment: Have you tried to define a foreign key? BTW, which Oracle version?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production, i haven't got problem with defining foreign key. Look at example

Comment: subqueries within check constraints are not allowed in oracle database, you may implement a trigger for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a trigger:

```
 CREATE TABLE TAB1 (
    TAB1_ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    TAB1_BOOL VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL CHECK (TAB1_BOOL IN('OPT1', 'OPT2'))
 );

 CREATE TABLE TAB2 (
   TAB2_ID INT NOT NULL,
   FOREIGN KEY (TAB2_ID) REFERENCES TAB1 (TAB1_ID)
 );

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER CHECK_TAB2_ID
    BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON TAB2 FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE 
    CURSOR CHECK_CURSOR IS
        SELECT TAB1_BOOL
          FROM TAB1 
         WHERE TAB1_ID = :new.TAB2_id;
    V_TAB1_BOOL VARCHAR(4);
BEGIN
    OPEN CHECK_CURSOR;
    FETCH CHECK_CURSOR INTO V_TAB1_BOOL;
    IF (V_TAB1_BOOL <> 'OPT1') THEN
       CLOSE CHECK_CURSOR;
       raise_application_error(10000, 'Wrong value in TAB1');
    END IF;
    CLOSE CHECK_CURSOR;
END;

INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES (1, 'OPT1');
INSERT INTO TAB1 VALUES (2, 'OPT2');

INSERT INTO TAB2 (TAB2_ID) VALUES (1);
```

There is still a small error in the trigger above. I have currently no access to an Oracle database, so I can hardy fix it. Here's my [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57b2f).

***p.s.***: ok, just a `;` missing in the Fiddle - [here's](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f48f) an update.

Comment: Don't forget to check some points Tom Kyte made about triggers. Google for them, or start with this one: [The Trouble with Triggers](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/the-trouble-with-triggers)